# Angle calculation in 3D space

Tags: matlab

I have the end points for 2 two lines and I need to find angle between these 2 lines.

Similarly I have 60 such points in an Excel sheet, and I need to find the angles between the lines joining these 60 points. I need to find the angle between these line segments.

I want to do this in MATLAB :

```
D = xlsread('45_A.xls');
CosTheta = dot(D(i,:),D(i+1,:))/(norm(D(i,:))*norm(D(i+1,:)));
xlswrite('45_Aav',CosTheta);
```

This program I had written to repeat for 60 values in the excel sheet, i.e., I had put it in a loop. But some wrong values are being calculated, i.e., angle values in imaginary and real values are written in the excel sheet.. I think there is some problem with the calculation part. Can you please help ?

Comment: Can you please describe what you already have and where the problem lies? Is it reading in the Excel sheet, how to find the angle, how to display the result?

Comment: If you question is how to calculate the angle between two lines, you can just take a direction vector for each of the lines (lets call them u and v) then cosine of the angle between the two lines is the dot product between the two vectors divided by the product of their lengths (u^Tv/(|u||v|))

Comment: Please provide a clear question to a specific problem. As of now you are asking for a complete solution of your problem as it seems.

Comment: D = xlsread('45_A.xls');
CosTheta = dot(D(i,:),D(i+1,:))/(norm(D(i,:))*norm(D(i+1,:)));
xlswrite('45_Aav',ThetaInDegrees);       this program i had written to repeat for 60 values in the excel sheet, i.e., i had put it in a loop. but some wrong values are being calculated, i.e., angle values in imaginary  and real values are written inti excel sheet.. I think there is some problem with the calculation part.. can you please help..

Comment: I edited your question to include your comments : reading the code in the question will be easier. My guess is that you are much more gifted than me regarding spelling and grammar stuffs. Feel free to click on the edit button !

Answer (score 0):

The angle in degrees between two vectors u and v can be computed as

```
180/pi*acos(dot(u,v)/(norm(u)*norm(v)))
```

I tested this on the following randomly generated set of 60 vectors, following your formula:

```
D = (10*rand(60,3)-5);    % random matrix 60 by 3
for i=1:size(D,1)-1 
    angleInDegrees = 180/pi*acos(dot(D(i,:),D(i+1,:))/(norm(D(i,:))*norm(D(i+1,:))));
    disp(angleInDegrees);
end
```

No imaginary values were obtained.

The above assumes that the vectors contained in D are the ones between which you want to find angles. If the array you have contains points P, and you want to find angles between lines connecting these points, then you first need to subtract the coordinates of adjacent points. Like this:

```
points = (10*rand(60,3)-5);   % random matrix 60 by 3
D = diff(points,1);           % differences between consecutive rows
```

and the rest as above.

Comment: I've have to write back the result into excel sheet as a single row. how can i do it

Comment: Writing data from Matlab to Excel is a separate question.

Comment: I mean that, after I calculate the angle in degrees, the values should be written into an excel sheet as a single row from matlab, how can I do it?